# Where to relearn algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request

I need a recommendation for a book for relearning basic algebra and re-understanding concepts like logarithms ans so on...any recommendation?In the past I've used Basic mathematics By serge lang ,I want something different.

Comment: Most introductory texts on calculus contains such a section.

Comment: Try to find a used copy of "Saxon Algebra 1/2".  I used it in high school around the turn of the century and it was fine.  I'm sure they're cheap online.

Comment: I ordered Higher Math for Beginning Physicists and Engineers by zeldovich ,does it have that?

Comment: Maybe "Schaum's" precalculus, or something else in their collection has hundreds, maybe even more than a thousand solved problems.

Answer (score 2):

An online reference book that may help is ["A Quick Algebra Review"](http://www.hood.edu/uploadedFiles/Hood_College/Home/Campus_Services/Academic_Services/Exams_and_Placement_Services/2011.02.23%20FINAL%20COPY%20-%20A%20Quick%20Algebra%20Review.pdf)

If you are interested in online tutorials, here are a couple examples:

- Video tutorials from [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra), where the videos cover a range of algebraic topics from the basics.
- [Algebra.help](http://www.algebrahelp.com/) - a collection of resources across several levels, also includes calculators and worksheets.

I hope these help.

Answer (score 2):

For books, I highly recommend the Saxon math texts.  You'd probably most benefit from their Algebra 1 or Algebra 2 textbook.

Also, I second Damien's recommendation of Khan academy. Those videos are really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This book is by one of the great mathematicians, I. Gelfand. It is a real classic as he uses his insight to really teach the subject. You will learn and gain a lot of insight.

[http://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Israel-M-Gelfand/dp/0817636773](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817636773)

Answer (score 0):

I am creating some autocorrected step-by-step tutorials on proving theorems, including those at the pre-calculus level, at the following location: http://www.public-domain-materials.com/folder-student-exercise-tasks-for-mathematics-language-arts-etc---autocorrected.html

The tutorials include, for example, proving the infinitude of primes, the irrationality of the square root of 2, and deriving the Quadratic Formula.